# Facebook activity feed does not show up on website, help needed

Tags: facebook

I set up a Joomla website for a client of mine with a box on the frontpage that should show the recent feeds of their facebook page. When I test it with a different page, it works. So obviously has something to do with their facebook settings.

Could anyone help me or tell me what might be wrong? Any constructive answer I would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought and by no means a definitive answer but are there any other social media plugins installed? I had an issue on a Wordpress site whereby the box displaying who likes my page wasn't showing as there was a conflicting javascript stopping it from displaying. Turns out it was another plugin using a slightly different Facebook .js